# Xamarin Android app is no longer being correctly verified by Firebase since using the phone # on a different phone

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin.forms

I have two real test phones (A and B) and both have actual phone numbers.
For testing purposes I logged into the app on phone A using B's phone number.  The 6 digit code went to B and I placed it in the app in phone A and was able to use B's account on A.  That worked fine.  The problem now is when I try to log back into the app in phone B using the phone # of B the verification check is coming back as null.  The line of code that is returning null is this:

```
var verificationResult = await CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumberAsync(CrossFirebaseAuth.Current.Instance, mobileNumber);
```

This was working before I used B's phone # on A.    This is always true now:  verificationResult.VerificationId == null

But I can still log into that account using phone A.  (I can still log into phone A's account on phone A too.)

My app is a Xamarin app (Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2012) and I am using the Nuget package Plugin.FirebaseAuth (tried 3.1 and 4.1).

I also literally deleted the phone number in the Firebase console and recreated the account and this is still happening.

What is happening?  Is there a way to force this to start working again on phone B?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I was testing a debug version on my phone that was using a local certificate.  I was using this local certificate in my Firebase Authentication.  I didn't realize when my Android app is published in the Google Play store that it is given a different certificate to use.  Once I copied the SHA text and added another SHA to my app in the Firebase console it started working just fine.

I find it funny how it is easier to setup iOS apps in the Google Firebase Authentication than it is for Android apps...